Reset display settings to defaults
How do I reset display settings to default distribution settings?
The two monitors on my laptop stopped working one after the other. Now, I've connected a completely different monitor, but still can't get it working. I think I've messed it up and would like to completely reset so it will detect and auto configure.
Ubuntu 22.04
HP ZBook Fury
